# Loop through char array line by line

Tags: c

I know how to loop through a file line by line by reading into a FILE* using fopen, fgets etc 
but how can i look through a char array line by line using plain C?
i have googled a lot an can only find stuff that reads from a file.

Comment: Please be more specific to the question. It is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I simply want to loop through a char array and display each line in plain C. Essentially i want to use fgets with a char array not a stream

Comment: @SnakeByte you can't do that directly, it's up to you to separate out what you consider to be each line, typically by searching for the `\n` character. The `strtok()` function can make this easier for you once you figure out how to use it; search for examples and go from there.

Comment: @mah i knew that '\n' represents a new line but just didn't know which way to go about looking for them. thanks for the point in the right direction.

Comment: @SnakeByte the answer RafedNole posts, while needing work, sparked what should have been an obvious thought: you can simply `printf()` your character array like any other string; if it's a single char array with multiple lines in it, they'll all print. Much easier than breaking things up, unless you need them broken up for other processing along the way.

Comment: corrected my hasty code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *sgets(char *s, int n, const char **strp){
    if(**strp == '\0')return NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;++i, ++(*strp)){
        s[i] = **strp;
        if(**strp == '\0')
            break;
        if(**strp == '\n'){
            s[i+1]='\0';
            ++(*strp);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==n-1)
        s[i] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main(){
    const char *data = "abc\nefg\nhhh\nij";
    char buff[16];
    const char **p = &data;

    while(NULL!=sgets(buff, sizeof(buff), p))
        printf("%s", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading a character array line by line : What does a line mean ? '\n' Perhaps.

so, iterate through the array.

```
 int main()

{  char array[10]="ab\nbc\ncd\n";

 int lines =0;int i=0;

 while(array[i]!='\0')

 { if(array[i]!='\n')

      printf("%c",array[i++]); 

       else { lines++;i++;    printf("\n"); } 
 }  return 0;

 }
```

Comment: If your text were: `ab\nbc\ncd\n` and you removed the `;` on your `if` statement and assuming you initialized i to 0, your code would end up printing `ab\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n...`. Might want to increment `i` somewhere else.

Comment: I would have just put a single `i++` at the bottom of the loop personally, thought the OP didn't state his intention was to print each line out (which a single print of the entire array would do more efficiently than one printf for each char)... if he needs the lines individually separated out, there's more work to do.

Comment: well, that's another question at all.He asked looking through the array line by line.Anyways, i++ is ok as long as it increments only once, better to have them at the bottom, sure.

Comment: I don't think it really is a second question (I don't speak for the OP of course!)... I think if he only intended to print the array lines out, there would not be any question at all. While he's not saying how he wants to "look through a char array line by line" it seems to me that your current code is "looking through a char array character by character" (where for your example, "look" = "print")... if you truly want to do some line oriented processing your code is close but not there. A little extra work would bring it much further.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to keep your separator flexible (e.g. you got `"\r\n"`) and stick to libraries, [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) is handy:

```
#include <cstring>
int main() {
    const char separator[3] = "\r\n";
    char text[13] = "ab\r\ncd\r\nef\r\n";
    char *line = NULL;
    line = strtok(text, separator);
    while (line != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", line);  // call your function to process line
        line = strtok(NULL, separator); // NULL means continue from where the previous successful call to strtok ended
    }
    system("pause"); // just prevent console from closing
}
```