# C read in string instead file

Tags: c, string

I have this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE *file = fopen("text", "rb");
  char line[128];
  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
  {
  printf("%s", line);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to remove the load from the file.
This is part of the program.
I want to leave while fgets
I try this

```
char file[] = "name = xxxx\nsurname = xxx\n adress = xxx";
```

Comment: I did not understand your question, can you explain please?

Comment: `I would like to remove the load from the file` what do you mean by this?

Comment: Are you expecting that the input is to be taken from the array ?????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300544/971127

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, and you're on a system that supports it, [`fmemopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) might do what you want.