# C replace file to string inside program

Tags: c, string

I have a program that reads data config from file xxx.conf

```
FILE *file = fopen("xxx.cof", "rb");
```

then the data are given as

```
char line[128];
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
```

I would like to replace file xxx.conf to string file = "name = xxxx\nsurname = xxx\n adress = xxx"

I wish the program to read data from a string.

Instead

```
FILE *file = fopen("xxx.conf", "rb"):

file = "name = xxx\nsurnam =xxx\nadress = xxx"
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what do you want to do with file.

Comment: Explain clearly what you have to do in that file?

Comment: Instead of asking again, you should perhaps fix your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480312/c-read-in-string-instead-file  This one is just as unclear as your first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use strtok

```
  char line[] = "name = xxx\nsurnam =xxx\nadress = xxx";

  char *entry;
  entry = strtok(line, "\n");

  while (entry)
    {
      printf("%s\n", entry);
      entry = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
```

Just replace printf by your code

Comment: No. Because I want to leave a line: while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))

Comment: i try:  char file[] = "name = xxx\nsurnam =xxx\nadress = xxx"

Comment: what do you mean by "leave a line"? You want to parse it line by line?

Comment: program is in a loop:   while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {...} with file xxx.conf retrieves data line by line. I want to enter a variable instead of a file.  file[] = ""name = xxx\nsurnam =xxx\nadress = xxx"